# returning data from then() returns Promise<void> instead of Promise<data>

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I'm getting data from an API as follows:

```
export const getSymbolStats = async (symbol: string) => {
let requiredData: IRequiredSymbolStats;
let request: Promise<AxiosResponse> = axios.get(`${api.baseURL}${api.symbolStats}`, {params: {symbol}});

request.then((res: AxiosResponse<ISymbolStats>) => {
    const symbolStats: ISymbolStats = res.data;

    // Destructure symbol stats.
    const highPrice: string = symbolStats.highPrice;
    const lowPrice: string = symbolStats.lowPrice;
    const priceChangePercent: string = symbolStats.priceChangePercent;
    const volume: string = symbolStats.volume;
    const weightedAvgPrice: string = symbolStats.weightedAvgPrice;

    // return an object with the required data.

    requiredData = {
        symbol,
        highPrice,
        lowPrice,
        priceChangePercent,
        volume,
        weightedAvgPrice,
    };
    return requiredData;
})
}
```

and retrieving the data inside this function:

```
export const getStats = async (msg: Message, match: RegExpExecArray | null): Promise<void> => {
  const id = msg.chat.id;
  const symbol: OrUndefined<string> = validateSymbol(id, match);
  if (!symbol) return;

  // make API call to get stats for symbol.
  let data = await getSymbolStats(symbol);

};
```

The `data` in the second function shows `void` rather than the `IRequiredSymbolStats` type that I returned inside the `then()` block. Why is this?

Comment: Why are you using `then` in an `async function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you declared your function as `async` there is no need to use
   `then`.
2. What you return from `then` is going nowhere because you don't store and don't return it from `getSymbolStats`

Just use `await` and store a result OR add `return` before `request.then`.

with `await` (more straight forward code, I'd prefer this way).

```js
const res: AxiosResponse<ISymbolStats> = await axios.get<ISymbolStats>(`${api.baseURL}${api.symbolStats}`, {params: {symbol}});

const symbolStats: ISymbolStats = res.data;

// Destructure symbol stats.
const highPrice: string = symbolStats.highPrice;
const lowPrice: string = symbolStats.lowPrice;
const priceChangePercent: string = symbolStats.priceChangePercent;
const volume: string = symbolStats.volume;
const weightedAvgPrice: string = symbolStats.weightedAvgPrice;

// return an object with the required data.

requiredData = {
  symbol,
  highPrice,
  lowPrice,
  priceChangePercent,
  volume,
  weightedAvgPrice,
};
return requiredData;
```

adding `return`:

```
let request: Promise<AxiosResponse> = axios.get(`${api.baseURL}${api.symbolStats}`, {params: {symbol}});

return request.then((res: AxiosResponse<ISymbolStats>) => {
    const symbolStats: ISymbolStats = res.data;

    // Destructure symbol stats.
    const highPrice: string = symbolStats.highPrice;
    const lowPrice: string = symbolStats.lowPrice;
    const priceChangePercent: string = symbolStats.priceChangePercent;
    const volume: string = symbolStats.volume;
    const weightedAvgPrice: string = symbolStats.weightedAvgPrice;

    // return an object with the required data.

    requiredData = {
        symbol,
        highPrice,
        lowPrice,
        priceChangePercent,
        volume,
        weightedAvgPrice,
    };
    return requiredData;
})
```